# how to optimize my oracle query?

Tags: database, oracle, performance, indexing

I have a query very slow and I want to optimize it. I've created index on fields for the joins. My query is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          --a.row_id FK_SERVIZIO,
          --CLI_UNICO.FK_CLIENTE FK_CLIENTE,
          CLI.CDC_FISCALE CDC_FISCALE,
          --com.descrizione
          --CASE WHEN conc.COMUNE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FL_OFFERTABILITA_GAS
          CASE WHEN exists (select 1 from STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ASSET_G a where a.owner_accnt_id=CLI.IDC_CLIENTE_CRM_KEY and status_cd in ('ATTIVATO'))
          THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END FLC_COMUNE_TERR

FROM     STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ASSET_G A,
         STG.T_STG_PSP_DT_LISTA_COMUNI_TERR terr,
         STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_R2DG_COMUNI_G com,
         STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ADDR_PER_G ind_for,
         --STG.V_DML_NBA_SITO q,
         ODS.T_ODS_CRM_DT_CLIENTI_CRM CLI,--ODS.V_ODS_NBA_DT_ASS_CLI_CLIUNICO CLI_UNICO,
         STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ORG_EXT_G cforn  
         --STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_R2DG_CONCESS_G conc,


WHERE 

    --CLI.IDC_CLIENTE_CRM_KEY=A.OWNER_ACCNT_ID 
    terr.LDS_DESCRIZIONE_COMUNE=com.DESCRIZIONE
    AND com.CODICE_ISTAT=ind_for.x_cod_istat
    AND ind_for.row_id = cforn.PR_ADDR_ID
    and cforn.row_id=A.serv_acct_id
```

i put index on this fields:

```
terr.LDS_DESCRIZIONE_COMUNE,com.DESCRIZIONE,com.CODICE_ISTAT,ind_for.x_cod_istat,ind_for.row_id,cforn.PR_ADDR_ID,cforn.row_id,A.serv_acct_id,a.owner_accnt_id,CLI.IDC_CLIENTE_CRM_KEY, a.status_cd.
```

any tips for me pls?
i can use PARALLEL? how?
THANKS

Comment: 6 tables and only 4 joins looks fishy to me!

Comment: there are 5 join, there is also: 
    select 1 from STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ASSET_G a where a.owner_accnt_id=CLI.IDC_CLIENTE_CRM_KEY and status_cd in ('ATTIVATO'))

Comment: WHERE 
(1)    terr.LDS_DESCRIZIONE_COMUNE=com.DESCRIZIONE
(2)    AND com.CODICE_ISTAT=ind_for.x_cod_istat
(3)    AND ind_for.row_id = cforn.PR_ADDR_ID
(4)    and cforn.row_id=A.serv_acct_id
(5)    ???

Comment: look at begin:  SELECT DISTINCT
          
          
          CLI.CDC_FISCALE CDC_FISCALE,
          --com.descrizione
          --CASE WHEN conc.COMUNE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FL_OFFERTABILITA_GAS
          CASE WHEN exists (select 1 from STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ASSET_G a where a.owner_accnt_id=CLI.IDC_CLIENTE_CRM_KEY and status_cd in ('ATTIVATO'))

Comment: and how i can modify my query?

Answer (score 0):

A sub select in the Select-Clause can hamper your performance badly. Just try to get rid of it.

You could do something like that

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          --a.row_id FK_SERVIZIO,
          --CLI_UNICO.FK_CLIENTE FK_CLIENTE,
          CLI.CDC_FISCALE CDC_FISCALE,
          --com.descrizione
          --CASE WHEN conc.COMUNE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FL_OFFERTABILITA_GAS
          decode(test.cnt, 0 'NO', 'SI') FLC_COMUNE_TERR

FROM     STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ASSET_G A,
         STG.T_STG_PSP_DT_LISTA_COMUNI_TERR terr,
         STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_R2DG_COMUNI_G com,
         STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ADDR_PER_G ind_for,
         --STG.V_DML_NBA_SITO q,
         ODS.T_ODS_CRM_DT_CLIENTI_CRM CLI,--ODS.V_ODS_NBA_DT_ASS_CLI_CLIUNICO CLI_UNICO,
         STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ORG_EXT_G cforn,
         --STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_R2DG_CONCESS_G conc,
         (select count(*) cnt from STG.T_STG_NBA_DT_S_ASSET_G a where a.owner_accnt_id=CLI.IDC_CLIENTE_CRM_KEY and status_cd in ('ATTIVATO')) test


WHERE 

    --CLI.IDC_CLIENTE_CRM_KEY=A.OWNER_ACCNT_ID 
    terr.LDS_DESCRIZIONE_COMUNE=com.DESCRIZIONE
    AND com.CODICE_ISTAT=ind_for.x_cod_istat
    AND ind_for.row_id = cforn.PR_ADDR_ID
    and cforn.row_id=A.serv_acct_id
```